# SAS:how to extract year/month/date from a marco variable and add an integer?

Tags: sas

```
proc sql;
select max(data_bsn_dt) into:date01 from tableA;
quit;

%put &date02;
```

print out:31DEC2017

```
%put year("&date01"d);
```

print out:year("31DEC2017"d)

I used code:year("&date01"d) to extract year or month before,but it does not work now..could some have time solve,thanks.

Even in the data step,it still not working..

```
data _nulll;
if year("&date01"d)=2017
then call execute('proc sql;
                   select * from tableB;');
run;
```

Comment: How is `date02` macro variable assigned? What data type is variable `data_bsn_dt` and what is it's SAS format ? If `date02` is a typo for `date01` then the likely way that `max(data_bsn_dt)` prints out `31dec2017` is that `data_bsn_dt` is a character variable that varies from '"01dec2017'" to `"31dec2017"'. Why ? because SQL MAX does not format it's result to be the same as the items it is finding the max of.  Use `OPTIONS SYMBOLGEN` to log how macro variables are being resolved.  Single valued intos prevent extra spaces with SQL `trimmed`, i.e. `max(variable) INTO :myVar trimmed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you are calling it outside of a procedure or data step.

To have it work in this context, you need to wrap it in `%SYSFUNC`:

```
%PUT %SYSFUNC(YEAR("&DATE01"d));
```

To add an integer, you can use `%EVAL` (e.g.):

```
%PUT %EVAL(%SYSFUNC(YEAR("&DATE01"d))+7);
```